# How to eliminate both direct and indirect left recursion?

Tags: parsing, compilation, context-free-grammar, left-recursion

For this grammar:

```
A -> B a | A a | c
B -> B b | A b | d
```

How to remove the left recursion?

====== My attempts ======

1. Eliminate direct left_rec first.

> ```
> A -> (B a | c) A'
> A' -> a A' | ε
> B -> (A b | d) B'
> B' -> b B' | ε
> ```

2. Then indirect. Put B into A.

> `A -> A b B' a A ' | d B' A' | c A'`

And then I got:

```
A -> (d B A' | c A') A''
A' -> a A' | ε
A'' -> b B' a A' A'' | ε
```

This result is quite complicated. How can I use only one A' to represent this?

Comment: For this relatively simple grammar, you can try to understand the language it generates, and then create a new grammar for the language using only right recursion. If you're having trouble understanding the language, try generating a bunch of strings and seeing what you get.